# Is there a smart way to send a String between two classes that are not supposed to interract with eachother?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

I should begin to say that I am quite new to Java. I am trying to write a simple chat program and thought it would be nice to have "popup" messages, for example if the intended message did not send or if the input was invalid etc. I handle most of the visual updates via observer-patterns, however I need to alter a Field in a class called GUIModel, from my ClientModel - the names are less relevant - which should not be coupled as far as I have understood it (since both are of type Model in a MVC system which i think should function independently).

Here are some snippets of my code:

```
public class Model implements ObservableMsg, ObservableSysMsg {

    private final ArrayList<Message> localHistory;
    private final String userID;
    private final ObservableMsgSupport obsMsg = new ObservableMsgSupport();
    private final ObservableSysMsgSupport obsSMsg = new ObservableSysMsgSupport();

    ...

    public void send(String msg) {
        try {
            Message newMsg = new Message(msg, this.userID, new Date());
            appendMsg(newMsg); //This is temporary until backend is implemented

            obsMsg.updateMsg();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR! Could not send msg.");
            //TODO Here is an example of where a popup message might be called to appear

            obsSMsg.updateSysMsg();
        }
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void addObserver(ObserverMsg o) { obsMsg.addObserver(o); }

    @Override
    public void removeObserver(ObserverMsg o) { obsMsg.removeObserver(o); }

    @Override
    public void addObserver(ObserverSysMsg o) { obsSMsg.addObserver(o); }

    @Override
    public void removeObserver(ObserverSysMsg o) { obsSMsg.removeObserver(o); }
}
```

```
public class GUIModel implements SystemMsgHandler, ObservableSysMsg {

    private final Set<String> systemMsgs;
    private final ObservableSysMsgSupport obs = new ObservableSysMsgSupport();

    public GUIModel() {
        systemMsgs = new HashSet<String>();
    }

    @Override
    public void addSystemMsg(String msg) {
        systemMsgs.add(msg);
        obs.updateSysMsg();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeSystemMsg(String msg) {
        systemMsgs.remove(msg);
        obs.updateSysMsg();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getSystemMsgs() { return systemMsgs; }

    @Override
    public void addObserver(ObserverSysMsg o) {
        obs.addObserver(o);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeObserver(ObserverSysMsg o) {
        obs.addObserver(o);
    }
}
```

```
public class GUIView implements ObserverMsg, ObserverSysMsg {
    
    ...

    @Override
    public void updateSysMsg() {
        popupPanel.removeAll();
        viewModel.getSystemMsgs().forEach(errMsg ->
                popupPanel.add(new ErrorPopup(viewModel, errMsg).getContentPane()));

        this.frame.revalidate();
        this.frame.repaint();
    }
}
```

I have tried to use an observer-pattern and it might very well be possible to solve the problem in such a way. However - as you can see - also judging by the size of the program, it seems to be quite redundant to use three different observer-patterns, two of them only to add and remove the popup messages. Therefore I was wondering if there is a different way of solving this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `send` being called from?  If `send` throw the Exception you could catch it and print the message from where it is caught.

Comment: Its called from another class called GUIController. And it worked, ty!